# My UIActionSheet isn't clickable, and now I can't do anything

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios-simulator, uiactionsheet

I open a UIActionSheet with [actionSheet openInView:view] ... and it opens in the iPhone simulator.  And you can't click on it.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to provide more information. What context is the action sheep used in, show your code. Have you told it to open beneath another view that could be preventing touches from reaching the action sheet?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is one particular issue with action sheets where the cancel button is not touchable when you present a UIActionSheet from a view inside a tab bar controller. To work around this you should present the action sheet from the tab bar controller's view:

```
[actionSheet openInView:self.tabbarController.view];
```

Comment: It turns out that if you set it to come out of any view that doesn't cover the bottom part of the screen, the part that overflows said view won't be touchable.  Best to just do [actionsheet openInView:self.view.window] maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You should also check if your view (from which you are showing the actionsheet) is touchable or not means if the view's userinteraction is not disabled. If this is alright then check for Mike Weller's answer.

Hope this helps,
Thanks,

Madhup